# How to rearrange pixels of an image with optimized approach

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a gray-scale image. I divided the image into blocks of size 128x128. I've implemented the following code, and it works correctly. However, it is highly time-consuming due to the use of four nested for loops. Is there a way to optimize it to achieve the same result but faster? The block size is set to 128, where blocksize[0] equals 128. The number of blocks in the row direction in the 'Image_input' is 68 (num_block_row), and in the column direction, it is 54 (num_block_col).
In fact, I intended to arrange the first pixels of each block side by side. In the attached image, each block consists of four pixels, each with a distinct color. I aim to arrange the pixels with a red color side by side within each block. This process should be applied to other blocks as well.

```
for t in range(blocksize[0]):

    for s in range(blocksize[0]):

        for i in range(num_block_row):

            for j in range(num_block_col):

               Image_result[(t*num_block_row) + i ,(s*num_block_col) + j] = Image_input[(i * blocksize[0]) + t, (j * blocksize[0]) + s]
```

I tried to rearrange the pixels of the image, but it was very time-consuming. Is there an optimized method to do it?

[image]

Comment: learn about numpy slicing operations. -- a pure python loop is slow. if you have to keep doing that, at least apply numba jit optimization.

Comment: since your code works but you want it to perform better, perhaps take this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Christoph the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se] (at the moment, it's not even a MCVE, never mind _full code in context_). You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Use *numpy* slicing operations.

```
red    = source[0::dy, 0::dx]
green  = source[0::dy, 1::dx]
blue   = source[1::dy, 0::dx]
purple = source[1::dy, 1::dx]

tiled = np.block([[red, green], [blue, purple]])
```

`dx, dy` are probably what you call `blocksize[0]` but I can't be quite sure because your code isn't a MRE.

Comment: Hello Christoph. Thank you for your answer. You know, I first divided each image to blocks 128x128 (blocksize[0] x blocksize[0]). Then number of blocks in rows are 68 (num_block_row = 68) and the number of blocks in columns is 54 (num_block_col = 54). My image was an example. In this image, instead of 128x128, I consider 5x5 blocks and red color is the first pixel of each block. In each row, there are two blocks 5x5 and in each column two blocks 5x5. I want to rearrange pixels in the image.